# Integrate DocuSign with Unit4

Tags: c#, api, cloud, docusignapi

I am being tasked to implement an integration between DocuSign and our new ERP system Unit4. When a user fills out a DocuSign form, the data will need to flow into Unit4. I do not have a lot of experience with APIs and wonder if someone could please provide some guidance on how to approach this task? Do I need to create a web service for these 2 systems to talk? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Comment: WELCOME to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Your project is not a simple one. If you haven't used APIs before, then you have a long learning curve in front of you, especially with C#.

In brief:

1. Figure out a way to get the data into Unit4. Look at their APIs.
2. Build a test program that takes canned data and gets it into Unit 4 the way that you want
3. Create a DocuSign envelope or template that collects the data that you want
4. Who will send out the DocuSign envelopes? Your application or will people do it manually from the DocuSign web app? Or do you want the signers to initiate the process, perhaps from a DocuSign PowerForm.
5. Once the DocuSign envelopes are fully signed, your application takes the data out of the DocuSign envelope and feeds it into Unit4.
6. How will your application be notified that an envelope is complete? One good way is to use webhooks: your application will be proactively notified when an envelope has been completely signed. If your application is behind your firewall, then you should look into using AWS/Azure, etc to buffer the notifications. See my [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4)

Also, check out DocuSign's example apps via our [QuickStart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) which demonstrate many of the DocuSign-related steps.

As I say, this is not a small project. I recommend that you consider hiring an experienced software developer or consultant if you want the project to succeeed.